# Storing results of a function into an object

Tags: arrays, function, variables, store, save

I'm having a problem getting the results of a function to be stored into an object. Return seems to stop the loop from getting all my array values and I constantly get undefined when I reference numbers2 in my object by setting either the return or console.log as a variable. I need to get the multiplied values into the numbers2 empty array. Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
   var numbers = [1,2,3,5];
   var numbers2 =[];
   function doubler(numbers){
      for(i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
         console.log(numbers[i]*2);
      }
   };
   /*doubler(numbers);*/
   object=new Object();
   object.type1 = numbers;
   object.type2 = numbers2;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers2 is undefined when you reference it because you are only logging the values out in your loop, not adding them to numbers2.  Hope this helps.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
var numbers = [1,2,3,5];
var numbers2 =[];
function doubler(numbers){
  for(i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
    console.log(numbers[i]*2);
    numbers2.push(numbers[i] * 2);
  }
};
doubler(numbers);
object=new Object();
object.type1 = numbers;
object.type2 = numbers2;

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your push method and it seems to make sense conceptually however, it is not adding anything to the empty array?

Comment: Looks like I got it working! I forgot to put the callback doubler(numbers) in. The data passes now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the object variable, change line 13 in your code to:

```
var object = new Object();
```

Also it would be nice if you could format your code in the future like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
    var numbers = [1,2,3,5];
    var numbers2 =[];
    function doubler(numbers){
        for(i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
            console.log(numbers[i]*2);
        }
    };
    /*doubler(numbers);*/
    object=new Object();
    object.type1 = numbers;
    object.type2 = numbers2;

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax help!